# GitBash integration in Sublime Text Editor

Tags: sublimetext3

Is it possible? 
I have insalled Terminal package for Sublime and insertred

> "terminal": "C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe"

in Terminal.sublime-settings configuration file.

Now I can open gitbash with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> from inside Sublime Text Editor, but it's looks like no way to open current or project folder, like when using cmd.exe. I whant to find normal integrated terminal like in the webstorm or in VSCode and wondering why it's still nothing like that in Sublime. Glue and so on is no way.

Comment: Press `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+T` to open the terminal at the project folder, assuming you're using the following terminal package. If not, use the following terminal package instead. https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Terminal

Comment: That is what I talking about. This options are not working with git-bash.

Comment: Works fine for me; my git bash contains a sh.exe and not a git-base.exe, though.